# How to move filter above the table header in GridView Widget in YII2?

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2

I am using Yii2 gridview widget.
I want to display filter above the header. Refer below image.
[image: I want to display filter above the header. Refer below image.]

Comment: but this is the normal  bootstrap 3 header position .. you use another css framework?

Comment: It's already working project. I cant change. Isnt there something I can do in yii2 ?

Comment: if you can please update your question and add the actual gridview configuration code and a image of your actual gridview .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Use `GridView` as

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
.....
   'filterPosition' => \yii\grid\GridView::FILTER_POS_HEADER,
])?>
```

To [Read More](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$filterPosition-detail)

Comment: This is the better answer, I was not aware of this setting.

Answer (score 0):

This will move the filters to the top. Make sure if you have multiple GridViews on the page that you find the correct id, in this case `#w0-filters`.

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$("#w0-filters").insertBefore($("thead>tr"));
$("thead tr:nth-of-type(3)").remove();
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
?>
```